# How to put one image into another image and put text and a small image in that image(the last one)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a slider. How can I put one image into another image and
put text and a small image in that image(the last one)? I have put one image into another one with no problem by giving position:relative in for main div and giving the second image position:absolute. But the third part (putting small image and text in that image) is tricky. I gave the container of image and text position absolute, but it is positioned out of the image div. Maybe a small example could help. Thanks

```
#maincontainer{
    width:650px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

#image1container
{
    width: 650px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px; 
    left: 137px;
}
#image2container{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vurbjydw/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `background-image` CSS property of `<div>` elements in HTML. Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="image1container">
        <img src="small-image.jpg" alt="Small image />
        <p>Text in image</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS would look like this:

```
#maincontainer {
    background-image: url('main-container-image.jpg');
}
#image1container {
    background-image: url('image1-container-image.jpg');
}
```

From here, you could use CSS to position the elements as needed.